# Can I cut tile to follow the profile of a closet flange?

Tags: tile, closet, flange

If I mount the closet flange to the substrate, can I cut the tile to match the radius of the ring with a small gap between the tile and ring I.E 1/8"

Answer (score 1):

That is totally normal.  1/8" would actually be a superb cut.  The toilet hides the gap.

Comment: And grout should fill said gap, just don't get any in the bolt holes.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the closest flange is sitting on top of the subfloor instead of on top of the tile, then yes it works just get one of the thicker toilet wax rings. If big box store doesn't have one check a plumbing supply store, or you could *try* doubling up the rings.